# WP7 AdMob SDK doesn't Work

Tags: windows-phone-7, admob

I always get an error when I start an app with an AdMob BannerAd. I just added the control to the toolbox and copy pasted in in the form.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<my:BannerAd HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,522,0,0" Name="bannerAd1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

When I run the app I get this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException wurde nicht behandelt.
  Message=NullReferenceException
  StackTrace:
    bei Google.AdMob.Ads.WindowsPhone7.WPF.DisplayAdBase.<>c__DisplayClass3c.<LoadDisplay>b__38()
    bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
    bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
    bei System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
    bei System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
    bei System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
    bei System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
    bei System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
    bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
    bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
    bei System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
    bei System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
    bei System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [AldarIT SuperAds](http://www.aldarit.com/superads.html) for three production Apps with AdMob as primary ad provider. No problems so far after 5 Months.

Answer (score 0):

Im using http://wp7adrotator.codeplex.com/. Having no problems still on my app.
http://www.aldarit.com/superads.html is a good solution too. Used it before started using wp7adrotator. You might give it  a try too.

Hope it helps.